# Adding android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml without root?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Android's OpenAccessory on the Samsung Galaxy Note. When installing the app I get and error.

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

After digging it looks like I need to add `android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml` to `/system/etc/permissions/`

I tried:

```
adb push android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml /system/etc/permissions/
```

but I got a "Read-only file system" so I tried to remount the partition rw:

```
$ mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

but without root access I go the expected "Operation not permitted" error.

Is there any way to do this without root? or am I forced to root my phone to get this working?

Comment: You can not change system files without root. That's the whole point of it, that App developers don't mess around with the system files and break the system